# Including files in Child Themes

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, wp-register-script

Twenty Thirteen uses the following in functions.php: `require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php' );`. When I copy /inc/custom-header.php to twentythirteen-child, it isn't replaced. I can't use `require()` because two copies will be included. How this should be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_template_directory` looks in the parent theme for files.

> In the case a child theme is being used, the absolute path to the
>   parent theme directory will be returned. Use
>   get_stylesheet_directory() to get the absolute path to the child theme
>   directory.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

This file is not meant to be replaced. You will need to find another way to do what you need to do.

Perhaps [remove the function hooked here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/inc/custom-header.php#L64) and add your own?

Comment: I know about these functions but what if I need to replace contents of that particular file? So, Child Themes are only meant to allow editing of CSS and main template files? I can't update shortcode in its PHP file or modify custom-header.php mentioned above?

Comment: As I said, the file is not meant to be replaced. You can't replace it. Yes, only some files are replaceable.

Comment: Okay! I see it now. Indeed, I'll use hooks to replace such functionality. Too bad that not everything can be replaced.